# Owin service returning data in extremely small chunks when self hosted in windows service

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin

I have a self hosted ASP.NET Web Api project using Owin that I can't figure out why it seems responses take incredibly long to get responses. I'm seeing 600KB of data take upwards of 20 seconds. To test that it wasn't the machine I made a quick node/express app that returned the same data and deployed it and that takes milliseconds to get the data. In Chrome devtools I can watch the WebApi response download kilobytes at a time, **oddly enough it seems like its always 4KB at a time** while the node service seems to get everything at once. I'm at a loss. I've been battling this for days now. The two responses have the same headers, the same data, the same everything. Why does WebApi seem to want to give me incredibly small bits of data back.

**Edit**

We run our OWIN Web Api apps are windows services. it appears the way we chose to return our data was causing the issue

```
HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
result.Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data)));
result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

return result;
```

The default stream size appears to be 4KB

Comment: You need to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates what you're trying to do. From that, people can tell you what you're getting wrong.

Comment: @vendettamit I know I didn't post enough here. I was seriously at a loss of what even to post, I was looking for anything, but I think my friend just point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET streams were the cause of the performance issue. My buddy pointed out the 4KB chunk size to me so I went looking for anything that might be defaulting to 4KB and sure enough it was `StreamContent` our WebApi controllers return like this

```
HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
result.Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data)));
result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

return result;
```

`StreamContent` has a default buffer size of 4096. by upping the buffer to something larger like 1MB, which is probably too large and should be something like 256KB or 512KB, the performance is great.

```
result.Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response.jsonString)), 1000000);
```